# Lucene how to index in Database (Cassandra)

Tags: java, indexing, lucene, cassandra

I am just experimenting with Lucene and want to indexing objects in Database(Cassandra) as a table. But, I didnt realized out, how the indexing does work on Cassandra. Especially searching...

When i take a simple Example

Indexing in Lucene:

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new TextField("id", "Hotel-1345", Field.Store.YES));
doc.add(new TextField("description", "A beautiful hotel", Field.Store.YES));
writer.addDocument(doc);
```

then Lucene will create index File (C:..) And Querying works well, with indexSearcher. But...

Indexing Database?
I think i cant just create a simple table like that

```
Table1:  
ID        , Description
------------------
Hotel-1345, A beautiful hotel
```

How does the searching process of lucene works? How should the database structur be?

hope, i get some answers :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not look like a relational database table, instead Lucene uses the inverted index and cosine similarity formula for searching of any search words.

To better understand you need to look for various terminology and formula to be used in lucene,
you can check out it on lucene officially website,
https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_5_0/scoring.html#Query%20Classes

To index data you need to make use of the Lucene indexer and searcher API
use this pseudo code for indexing :

```
    Directory directory = null;
    IndexWriter writer = null;
    try {
        directory = FSDirectory.open(new File(args[0]));
        IndexWriterConfig iwConf = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_48,
                new KeywordAnalyzer());
        iwConf.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE);
        writer = new IndexWriter(directory, iwConf);
        Document document = new Document();
        document.add(new StringField("title", "Cat", Store.YES));
        writer.addDocument(document);
        writer.commit();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: you know which plugins, do i need to build the indexing process to database (cassandra)

Comment: check the updated answer with lucene code to index data that need to be read from the database

Comment: i didnt catch it, the code will write the document as File on Disc. What i want was, connect with database and index/search the Objects. But they should stay as index in database not on disk. I am confused :/

Comment: Lucene index created on disk and on that you can do search operation so after indexing it is independent of the database. You can not store index on database

Comment: Can you please accept the answer or if you need more clarification then please let me know

Comment: that means i have to index the object from Database to own disk, and then search like this image right?

  http://i.stack.imgur.com/MkPcE.png